# How to bind InputText to a model in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have a model class called Patient, a class that handles the services related to Patient, and an interface. All are public except the interface and all are in separate files. When i try to bind InputText on my Razor page to patient properties, the ide doesnt find them.

The razor page:

```
@using BlazorApp.Data;

<EditForm Model="@patient"> 
    <div class="col-12 row">
        <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">first name: </label>
        <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="patient.Name"/>
        placeholder="first name" />
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
public Patient patient {get;set;}
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    patient =  new Patient();
}
```

}

The model class:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Patient(){}

    public Patient(int id, string name, string lname, DateTime date)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        LastName = lname;
        DateOfBirth = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is with the namespaces... Set the right references in the _Imports.razor file

Comment: Added the the namespace to the imports file, issue still persists. @enet

Comment: What is the namespace of these classes? Did you try to add a using directives in the component in which you use them ?

Comment: the namespace is blazor, and yes they are added with using directives as well. @enet

Comment: Change the namespace, and don't use the word blazor anymore. I don't think it is related, but still you don't have to define a namespace like that. Now, please copy and paste here all the relevant namespace and using statements related, so I can see them in my own eyes.

Answer (score 0):

> When i try to bind InputText on my Razor page to patient properties, the ide doesnt find them.
>
> the namespace is blazor, and yes they are added with using directives as well.

I did a test based on your description and code, which work well on my side. Please recheck the namespace of your `Patient` class and make sure you have imported it via `@using` directives.

*Patient class*

```
namespace blazor 
{
    public class Patient
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public Patient() { }

        public Patient(int id, string name, string lname, DateTime date)
        {
            ID = id;
            Name = name;
            LastName = lname;
            DateOfBirth = date;
        }
    }
}
```

*In _Imports.razor*

```
@using blazor
```

*In component*

```
<EditForm Model="@patient">
    <div class="col-12 row">
        <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">first name: </label>
        <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="patient.Name" placeholder="first name" />
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code{
    public Patient patient {get;set;}

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        patient =  new Patient() {  Name = "test user"};
    }
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]